# I think I didn't write the routing correctly. Or the problem is in something else

Tags: angular, web, routes, navbar

I have a problem with Angular routing, I want the nav bar to remain and the background to change, but when I do this, the nav bar is written on top

[! [this is my routing file] (https://i.stack.imgur.com/p4yNi.png)] (https://i.stack.imgur.com/p4yNi.png)

[! [app component file] (https://i.stack.imgur.com/DecRF.png)] (https://i.stack.imgur.com/DecRF.png)
`

**this is my nav bar code**

```
<div class="back">
                <nav class="navbar">
                    <ul class="nav flex">
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" [routerLink]="['/explore']" href="#">00 HOME</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" [routerLink]="['/destination']" href="#">01 DESTINATION</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#">02 CREW</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#">03 TECHNOLOGY</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
```

`

[! [and this is my website] (https://i.stack.imgur.com/VQTZU.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VQTZU.jpg)

I tried to show the nav bar first from the router but that didn't work either and I gave the nav bar a background and then it just had the same background image. I am new to Angular and please help me

Comment: Please [edit] to paste the text used in the image into your question so that it can be read on all devices, quoted, edited, and found through search. As it stands now, [your image makes it hard to answer your question or for people with related issues to find your question](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question). See the [formatting documentation](/editing-help) for tips to make your text appear nicely without resorting to images.

Answer (score 1):

I've created a [stackblitz](https://angular-ivy-htnyyh.stackblitz.io) that handles what you're trying to achieve. I believe the issue may be that you haven't registered the `NavComponent` in the `AppModule`

1. In your App Module

```js
import { NavComponent } from './nav/nav.component';

@NgModule({
  imports: [BrowserModule, FormsModule, AppRoutingModule],
  declarations: [AppComponent, HelloComponent, NavComponent], //register your NavComponent
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
```

2. In your `Nav` html template file, we can toggle the active nav items

> NOTE: in the `routerLink`, since we are passing in a string, we don't need the '[]'

```html
<div class="topnav">
  <a routerLink="/explore" routerLinkActive="active">00 HOME</a>
  <a routerLink="/destination" routerLinkActive="active">01 DESTINATION</a>
  <a>02 CREW</a>
  <a>03 TECHNOLOGY</a>
</div>
```

3. In your `AppRoutingModule` we setup our routes like so:

```js
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { DestinationComponent } from './destination/destination.component';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { ExploreComponent } from './explore/explore.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: 'explore',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  {
    path: 'explore',
    component: ExploreComponent,
  },

  {
    path: 'destination',
    component: DestinationComponent,
  },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

Comment: can u send me a code of stack blitz

Comment: @saDpooro the stackblitz is included in the answer but here it is again: https://angular-ivy-htnyyh.stackblitz.io/